# Error parsing XML: not well-formed (invalid token) multicolumn ListView

Tags: android, xml, android-listview

I am trying to create a multicolumn List view and have created a new xml file in the layout folder called row.  However I got an error saying

> Error parsing XML: not well-formed (invalid token)

I cannot seem to find the problem although I think I have missed closing off a tag and or mistyped something.  Much appreciated!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >


<TextView
     android:id="@+id/name"
    android:gravity="left"
     android:layout_width="50dip"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<TextView
     android:id="@+id/path"
    android:gravity=”center”
     android:layout_width="70dip"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_weight="1" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You forgot closing tag for the layout </LinearLayout>.

Comment: @Onik I added that in just then however I still get the same error

Comment: + you have different double quotes here: `android:gravity=”center”`

Comment: I have also changed that and still getting the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >


<TextView
     android:id="@+id/name"
    android:gravity="left"
     android:layout_width="50dip"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<TextView
     android:id="@+id/path"
    android:gravity="center" <!-- this -->
     android:layout_width="70dip"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_weight="1" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Could you explain what the problem was?

Comment: android:gravity=”center” to android:gravity="center"